# Select two types information from same table in single query MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

[image: My 'users' table:]
I have a 'users' table like bellow. When a new user sign in, he has to use one 'sponsor_id' from previous user. Previous user's 'user_name' being used as 'sponsor_id' for a new user. Now, I want to show some 'sponsor_id' details when a new user signed in like, sponsor_id's first_name, last_name, phone etc. All data are saved in 'users' table. What should be the query,Please anyone help me. I am using Laravel5.4.
I am trying something like-

```
$sponsor_info = DB::table('users')
            ->select('first_name','last_name','phone')
            ->where('user_name', '=', '$sponsor_id')
            ->first();
```

Comment: self join the user table and fetch sponsor details

Comment: You should attempt to write a JOIN type query where the join is with the same table. You could do a query where you were selecting two users, where one is the sponsor, and one is the other.

Comment: Er the name is the id? What if the sponsor changes their name?

Comment: I want to show just sponsor details,but me and my sponsor is in the same table.

Comment: Try to upload smaller pic, so people would see only the column related to the question. Easier to understand you.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know laravel but Im giving the solution plz convert it to laravel.

```
select m.*,
       s.first_name,
       s.last_name,
       s.phone 
from user m 
left join user s 
 on m.sponsorid=s.userid
```

Comment: I did not understand m or s . User information and Sponsor information is in the same table.

Comment: They are aliases, `m` is the first instance of `users` and `s` is the second. , `m` represent users information and `s` represent `sponsor` information . @Md.RashedulHasan

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
   user.id,
   user.user_name,
   user.sponsor_id,
   sponsoredUser.user_name
   FROM user
   INNER JOIN user AS sponsoredUser ON user.sponsor_id = sponsoredUser.id
WHERE user.id = $id
```

Here I am using user table 2 times . First is using for that user and the second is using for the getting information of that sponsored user. That's why I given the second user table name an alias name called `sponsoredUser` . 
Hope you will transfer this query into laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Add this function to your user model:

```
public function sponsor()
{
   $this->belongsTo(App\User::class,'sponsor_id','user_name');
}
```

Now you can make this query:

```
$users = App\User::with('sponsor')->get();
```

All users will have a "sponsor" relation loaded.

```
Foreach ($users as $user){
   $user->sponsor->first_name;
   // Etc
}
```

Comment: I want to show 'sponsor_id's first_name, last_name. But it showing my user's first_name, last_name.  It's showing all data.